# Can I associate Excel buttons to a line so that they can be included in sort/filter?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, button, filtering

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet with VBA that allows the use of filters and sorting, with buttons associated to each line, as in the following picture:

[image]

When I sort/filter the sheet, the buttons don't naturally follow the sorting/filtering because they're not associated to the cells - so if I sort "Document Number Z to A" I'll have Y -> X, but the buttons will remain X->Y.
Is there anyway I can associate the buttons to the cell or any other way you guys can think of that would enable the buttons to be contemplated by the sorting/filtering?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of button are you using?  Forms, or ActiveX?  To be honest you'd find it much more reliable to use hyperlinks in stead of buttons, since they'd never end up getting mis-positioned.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660492/running-vba-from-a-hyperlink/32662063#32662063  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370308/activex-command-button-that-unhides-next-to-a-cell-if-a-value-is-entered-and-hi/56371769#56371769

Comment: This is a great idea that I hadn't thought of. Thanks a lot! I'll try to make it work with the hyperlinks and see if that works. Thanks for the references too! 
I was using Forms, by the way.