# How to repeat command button in each row in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm creating a table in excel where the user can use a command button to create a clickable link to a document.

The table has various formulas to calculate dates etc. and it is an excel table, not a range of cells in excel.

So far I have copied the button for about 100 rows.

How do I get the file link button to repeat for each row?

Comment: A button on every row goes against how Excel works. Can't you create the link with a formula?

Comment: Consider using hyperlinks instead of buttons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370308/activex-command-button-that-unhides-next-to-a-cell-if-a-value-is-entered-and-hi/56371769#56371769

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data in the table? I'm confused on how date calculations fit into this.

Comment: From what it sounds you need a FOR loop. But, providing a sample data would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Without the need of a CommandButton, the Code below combines `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and `Intersect` to create the link in the selected cell inside a specified Range as you click on it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("X3:X400"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Target, _
            Address:="hhtp:\\YourLinkAddress.org", _
            TextToDisplay:="Link"

    End If
End Sub
```

Modify it to your Needs. You will get the values of the Row by using `Target.Offset`